# Why my Webpack does not loading background image?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, webpack-file-loader

[image: that is my problem]

I'm fairly new to webpack but having some problems with css-loader or file-loader in react

I'm trying to load a background-image but it doesn't work quite right. The background-image isn't shown, even though the devtools show the background-image style.

I'm trying to load this background image via css file in React:
  background: url('../../assets/img/1017.jpg') no-repeat right;

here is my web pack config:

```
[![const path = require("path");

module.exports =
{
    mode: "development",
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname,`src`, `app`),
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath:'/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: \['.js','.jsx'\]
    },
    devServer:{
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    module: {
        rules:\[{
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            loader:'babel-loader',
            exclude: '/node_modules'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
            use: {
              loader: "url-loader",
              options: {
                limit: 25000,
              },
            },
          },

          {
            test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
            use: {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "\[path\]\[name\].\[hash\].\[ext\]",
              },
            },
          },
        {
            test:/\.css$/,
            use:\['style-loader','css-loader',\]
        },
       \]
    },
```

}

Comment: So what does your dev tools say? Specifically, does the console show any errors, and does the network tab show any 404 results?

Comment: I tried to load a image from  local folder, so there is no 404 error here. In the dev tools, the browser can not run css "background-image"

Comment: That seems pretty obvious then? Look at the URL that's a 404, and fix whatever is wrong with the path by changing whatever line of code is loading that obviously wrong URL (whether that's CSS or JS) so that it loads the _correct_ URL? (also, do _not_ load images in CSS as base64, let the browser cache images the way it was meant to. Just put the image in a static assets directory, and then point to that in your CSS. Don't create _massive_ css files, that's just making life miserable for your users)

Comment: I don't have 404 error at the URL, and I make sure that my URL is correct in my code. how I can fix  web-pack config file?

Comment: Sorry, I misread you. If there is no 404, but things don't work, then what does the console say? (And remember to turn off any filtering, you want to see _all_ errors, warnings, etc)

Comment: There is no error in my console, everything works fine, and my browsers realize my css file, expected the line "background-image: url(/src/app/assets/icons/shape.b55405126e3e1a1fe3c2905471f1401d.jpg) no-repeat center;"

Comment: So when you type `yoourdomain/src/app/assets/icons/shape.b55405126e3e1a1fe3c2905471f1401d.jpg` in your URL bar, that works fine? Because if it does, your CSS rule should work just fine, but if you CSS rule doesn't kick in, I find it hard to believe that URL actually works rather than being a 404.

Answer (score 1):

you have added **no-repeat** and **center** value in **background-image** property, instead you can use **background** property.

Comment: It would be better to write like this: "you should use" instead of "you can use"

Answer (score 0):

#### You have made mistake in css rule

You have used `background-image` with `no-repeat` and `center`. `background-image` accepts only `url(...)`. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

#### How to fix

Just replace `background-image` with `background`

```css
.loginLeft{
    background: url(data:image/...) no-repeat center
}
```